# Forming half equations

Tags: redox

I'm having trouble finding the ionic and half equations for the following equation:

$\ce{2Sr + O2 -> 2SrO}$

From this I would have to tell which elements are being oxidised and reduced.

This is [IGCSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_General_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education).

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{SrO}$ is an ionic compound comprising $\ce{Sr^2+}$ ion and $\ce{O^2-}$ ion.

The oxidation state of $\ce{Sr}$ changed from $0$ to $+2$, and $\ce{O}$ from $0$ to $-2$.

Therefore, $\ce{Sr}$ is oxidized while $\ce{O2}$ is reduced.

---

The ionic equation is just that, since there is no individual ion in the equation ($\ce{SrO}$ is a solid!).

---

Are you really told to find a half equation for a reaction not performed underwater?

Comment: So does the big number make a difference to the ionic equation?

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes Which big number?

Comment: If you see in my question, its 2Sr.

Comment: 2 is not a pretty big number imo.

Comment: And no, you can include it outright

Comment: How do I include it? I'm an IGCSE student not a university scholar.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes The ionic equation is $\ce{2Sr + O2 -> 2SrO}$